# meteorjs stop subscribtion of collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to stop a subscribtion process.

Currently this is my code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.autorun(function(){
        var query;
        query = Session.get('search.query');
        if (!query) return;
        if (Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion) {
            console.log('Subscribtion for search has to stop ... ');
            Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion.stop();
        }

        Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion = Meteor.subscribe('search', query, {
            onReady : function () {
                console.log('Finished.');
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Env is a global function where I temporaly save the subscribtions in `temp.searchSubscribtion`.

The problem now: I change the `search.query` value to a query to get all items. The finished console.log "Finished" displays after about 1 minute.

After this I change the `search.query` to a query which jsut get a few items. The Finished console.log displays after about 5 seconds.

As you see: A long query, and a small one.

What I want to do now is:

When a query was changed the currently subscribtion has to be canceld and the new subscribtion has to start, but:

When I set the long query and right(!) after this I change the search.query Session to the small query the "Finished" console.log displays after more than 1 minute.

The "`Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion.stop();`" executes rigth (I see the console log) but the susbcribtion does not stop - it seems that the server just finish the first susbcribtion and than finish the second one - like a queue.

Any ideas how to cancel a running subscribtion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the original query is taking that time to return, the single `Fiber` that runs your subscriptions will be stalled. You wont be able to send it any other subscription commands (stop / new subscription etc) until it completes.

You have a few options:

1. Make the query faster (indexes?)
2. Publish all documents [perhaps limit some fields], then search on the client. You can then subscribe to the full set of fields by sending a list of _id's
3. Don't use a publication, and send the data via `Meteor.methods` (non-reactive/auto-publish).
4. Combine 2 & 3; call a meteor method to do the query, that just returns a list of _id's, then subscribe to that list of `_id`'s
5. Do (4) except use a server-side route, to avoid blocking up meteor methods (if you're firing off a lot of method calls... )

Just be careful when using Meteor.methods to avoid blocking fibers you'll need to:

1. call from the client with `Meteor.apply('myMethod',[parameter1, parameter2 /* etc */], {wait: false}, callback);`
2. on the server call `this.unblock()` in the method body.

An example of (4):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods('search', function (query) {
    this.unblock();
    // some query logic??
    return _.pluck(collection.find(query, {_id: true}).fetch(), '_id');
  });

  Meteor.publish('searchResults', function (resultIds) {
    return collection.find({_id: {$in: resultIds}});
  });

}
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.autorun(function () {
    var query;
    query = Session.get('search.query');
    if (!query) return;
    Meteor.apply('search', [query], {wait:false}, function (err, resultIds) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error!', err);
        return;
      }
      var currentSearch = Session.get('search.query');
      if (!EJSON.equals(currentSearch, query)) {
        console.log('Results returned for', query, ' however current search is ', currentSearch);
        return;
      }

      if (Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion) {
        console.log('Subscribtion for search has to stop ... ');
        Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion.stop();

      }
      Envi.temp.searchSubscribtion = Meteor.subscribe('searchResults', resultIds, {
        onReady: function () {
          console.log('Finished for query:', query);
        }
      });
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: Hey Nathan. First thanks for the answer. But there is a problem when I use your code: When calling th Meteor.apply() method the "resultIds" always returns "null" as value. But when using a console.log in my Meteor.method (search) the result is a valid array. For testing I changed the hole msearch-method code to "return test" but the "resultIds" value is always "undefined".

Comment: I think that the "resultIds" is always undefined because of "wait:false". But when its not "wait:false" the method can not be canceld - right ?

Comment: Ah no, if forgot that the first parameter to the callback is the error, please see updated code!

Comment: Thanks for your trick, Nathan. This works liek a charm and now it increase the performance when I try to search again when another search is still in process. Thanks a lot!